# Why is the Guid changing when saving the record?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, oracle10g

I have an entity named 'Bid' and following is the code relevant to this question:

Class:

```
public class Bid
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping File:

```
<id name="Id" column="Id" type="Guid">
  <generator class="guid.comb" />
</id>
```

Datatype in Oracle:

```
Raw(16)
```

When I am saving a new object of type 'Bid' (Repository.Save(bid)) the Id generated by C# is

```
db27b33c75314b41b171a1620130061a
```

and the one saved in the oracle table is

```
3CB327DB3175414BB171A1620130061A
```

If you look carefully, the second half of the id is same, but the first half is not.

Can someone tell me how can I change my code so that the Id generated by C# gets saved as it is??

I have tried the generator classes 'assigned' and 'guid.native' and tried changing the datatype to varchar2(32) in oracle, but to no avail.

Comment: What if you change the column type to string (in mapping file and in th class) and assign the value manually to a new GUID?

Comment: i would try that, but a solution where the datatype in the database doesn't change would be ideal. I wouldn't mind changing the type in the mapping files or classes.

Comment: What is the NHibernate version? The oracle dialects have been designed to map C# Guid to RAW16.

Comment: I suspect the internal code responsible for saving the data to database is the culprit, so passing it raw string should solve the issue if that's really the case.

Comment: Not only is the second half the same, but the first half appears to be the same characters in a different order.  It looks like the first four characters have been switched with the second four, and then in each group of four characters, the first pair are switched with the second pair.  It's clearer if you separate the parts out: `db27b33c-7531-4b41-b171-a1620130061a` and `3CB327DB-3175-414B-B171-A1620130061A` This seems to be a GUID serialization issue.

Answer (score 2):

The first part is also the same, but with a different byte order. Reverse the byte order in each of the first three groups below and you will see this:

db27b33c 7531 4b41 b171a1620130061a

3CB327DB 3175 414B B171A1620130061A

There is some discussion on this here: https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1429

Comment: I have found out that there is a function called hextoraw() in oracle. The Id must be inserted into the table like this - `insert into table_name (id) values(hextoraw(guid_goes_here))`. Is there anyway we can tell nhibernate to call this function when inserting values into the Id column?

Comment: i have tried this solution, but the behavior hasn't changed a bit.

Answer (score 0):

To other people arriving from google, who are also new to nhibernate and mysql, in the .hbm.xml file I changed

```
<id name="Id" type="Guid">
  <generator class="guid" />
</id>
```

to

```
<id name="Id" type="Guid"/>
```

and my guids quit changing.